# Youtube playing audio many times

Tags: firefox, flash, youtube

Ubuntu 11.04, Firefox 6.0, Shockwave Flash 10.3 r183.  Every time I play a Youtube video, it starts playing the audio many times, so that I get many overlapping copies of the same audio at the same time.  They play whether or not the video is paused.  This doesn't happen on Vimeo, nor does it happen in Google Chrome.  Any ideas?

Edit: it also happens in Youtube's HTML5 mode.

Comment: Why don't you switch to a better browser then?

Comment: Because there are other things I like about Firefox, and if there's a nice fix, I'd prefer that to completely changing browsers and trying to find replacements for all my extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  For anyone else with this problem, for me it was a problem with a Greasemonkey script (Youtube HD Ultimate), causing the page to be reloaded in a weird way.

Answer (score 0):

Install this... let it do its magic and say yes to all its questions. Likely hood is that you'll get a newer/x64? version of flash and it will iron out bugs.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/

If that doesn't work try running firefox as sudo and check if it still does it... if thats the case it sounds like a permissions issue on a tmp folder.

Comment: Neither of those helped.

Comment: As a temporary relief, you can enable HTML5 mode on youtube. I would try checking my logs in /var/log/ then running firefox in safemode.

Comment: Edit: Actually, it happens in HTML5 videos on Youtube too...